# How to handle JSON/PHP array inside of array data

Tags: php, json

I thought it would be simple but of course I'm at a roadblock, I'm new to handling JSON data but here is the info.

```
$new_item = '[2554560000, 18.26]';
$load = file_get_contents("json/graphlist.json");
$data = json_decode($load, true);
var_dump($data);
echo "<br /><br />";
echo ($data['product1']);
echo "<br /><br />";
echo json_encode($data);


$save = file_put_contents('json/graphlist.json', json_encode($data));
```

JSON Data:

```
{"product1":[[243500000,17.85],[245500000,14.65],[248500000,16.22]]}
```

when I var_dump the decoded data it comes out as:

```
array(1) { ["product1"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(243500000) [1]=> float(17.85) } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(245500000) [1]=> float(14.65) } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(248500000) [1]=> float(16.22) } } }
```

yet when I echo the product1 array it only shows:

```
Array
```

So my question is how do I access the data within the second Array. Then append the data from $new_item to the existing strings to be saved back to the JSON file. I've looked everywhere yet I can't find anyone with similar examples or errors.

Comment: You can access the elements of the array by `echo $data['product1'][0][0];` or view the whole array by `print_r $data['product1'];`

Comment: Thank you also for your input on the print_r code, that also worked well in helping me to solve the coding. btw print_r I realized has to have its code blanketed with ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do

```
echo($data["product1"][0][0]);
```

instead, to get the first number out.

Comment: that definitely solves my issues when I was wanting to look at the data, hopefully this will help me figure out how to append the new data to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `echo` on an array, it will correctly just display `Array`.

If you want to access the data inside it, you can do something like:

`echo $data['product1'][0][0] // echoes '243500000'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `print_r()` to display the entire array.

```
 print_r($data['product1']);
```